# Fast way to calculate difference in normal CDFs

Tags: r, normal-distribution, computational-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

I'm running a computationally intensive method where I have to calculate the difference in Normal CDF's millions of times, such as

```
pnorm(y)-pnorm(x)
```

I have not looked into the details of how the CDF is calculated in R but I was thinking there may be a way to speed this up, perhaps into one pnorm call.  Or maybe there a mathematical simplification I can take advantage of.

Any suggestions (maybe it's not possible)?

Comment: Is there any relationship between y and x?

Comment: How much accuracy do you need? After all, you could replace `pnorm` by a table and just interpolate within it for a reasonably fast approximation.

Comment: No relationship between x and y.  @whuber Good point on the table, I could see a hash table type approach as a possible solution...

Comment: You don't need a hash table: just index directly into an array using a discrete version of $x$ and $y$. For instance, the linear interpolator `f` defined by `z <- pnorm(i <- seq(-6, 6, .01)); f <- approxfun(i, z)` will obtain results good to within 2% whenever $x$ and $y$ are more than $0.003$ apart (with relative accuracy increasing rapidly as $y-x$ increases). The linear interpolation is twice as fast as `pnorm`, which itself is very fast: my machine computes seven million values per second. Maybe your problem is with your coding style and not with `pnorm`?

Comment: I second that. It's hard to imagine pnorm being a bottleneck...

Comment: Thanks for the code @whuber, wasn't aware of approxfun function, very nice.  I also wasn't aware the pnorm function was so fast.  You are right, this is not a bottleneck as I originally thought it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a good 'one termer' approximation to $\Phi(x)$ is given by Polya's approximation:

$$(1)\;\;\;\Phi(x)\approx\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\text{sign}(x)\sqrt{1+\exp{\frac{-2x^2}{\pi}}}\right)$$

Below I place an R code:

```
aa<-seq(-5,5,l=1000)
x1<-pnorm(aa)
x2<-(1+sign(aa)*sqrt(1-exp(-2/pi*aa**2)))/2
plot(aa,x1)
lines(aa,x2,col="red")
legend("topleft",lty=c(1,1),lwd=c(1,1),col=c("black","red"),legend=c("pnorm","Polya's approximation"))
```

and a plot:

[image]

If you are willing to rewrite (1) in a compiled language it should be 
 faster than a call to [`pnorm`](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/pnorm.c) since the latter is a 
much more complicated function.

## EDIT

Just for fun I implemented Polya's approximation in `c++`. I got 
the following (modest) speed up over R's pnorm:

```
> system.time(fit1<-.C("R_fastPolya",as.integer(n),as.single(x),as.single(x)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.340   0.184   0.523 
> system.time(pnorm(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.856   0.024   0.879
```

e.g. a mere 40% speed up :( --though, my implementation is pretty naive--. Finally, the maximum relative error is slightly less than $\Phi(x)/100$.

Comment: The loss of accuracy in return for only a 4% speedup hardly seems worthwhile.  As you suggest, perhaps on other platforms this approach would have some merit.

Comment: @whuber: as you pointed out, comparing pnorm (implemented in C) to this R code is unfair. Apple to apple comparisons should favor the approximation though (it has lower numerical complexity than the approach used in [R](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/pnorm.c)...).

Comment: Unfair how? I have merely timed your code versus the code the OP is already using. *How* his code is implemented is hardly relevant, I would think: what matters (in addition to the loss of accuracy) is how the two perform and how much work would be needed to speed up your solution. Before you consider doing that, though, I would encourage you to revisit the issue of accuracy: the relative error of your approximation is reasonable only for arguments less than $2$ in size. It's unlikely that the arguments would be limited to that range during a simulation.

Comment: @whuber: by argument less than 2 in size, you mean x:|x|<=2?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The comments have pointed out that pnorm is already extremely fast, but I was not aware of this approximation and it is certainly useful.  I wonder how this would compare to a Taylor Expansion approximation...

Comment: Yes: when $|x| > 2$, the accuracy of the approximation drops drastically; soon it is returning values that are only 20% of the correct values.  For this reason I think it's a poor solution.